# Flask Cassandra Connection with Celery

Tags: python, flask, cassandra, celery, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to create cassandra connection when the celery worker process starts and close the connections when the worker shuts down.

I am using the below code for it.

```
thread_local = threading.local()

@worker_process_init.connect
def open_cassandra_session(*args, **kwargs):
  auth_provider = DSEPlainTextAuthProvider(username='simpl1', password='********')
  cluster = Cluster( ['public_ip1','public_ip2','public_ip3'], port=9042, auth_provider=auth_provider, address_translator=IdentityTranslator())
  session = cluster.connect('keyspace1')
  thread_local.cassandra_session = session

@worker_process_shutdown.connect
def close_cassandra_session(*args,**kwargs):
  session = thread_local.cassandra_session
  session.shutdown()
  thread_local.cassandra_session = None
```

When I start the celery worker, I get the below error

```
[2017-06-28 14:39:31,805: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Downgrading core protocol version from 65 to 4 for 54.255.180.2. To avoid this, it is best practice to explicitly set Cluster(protocol_version) to the version supported by your cluster. http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver-dse/latest/api/dse/cluster.html#dse.cluster.Cluster.protocol_version
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,268: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Using datacenter 'ap-southeast_1_cassandra' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (via host '54.255.180.2'); if incorrect, please specify a local_dc to the constructor, or limit contact points to local cluster nodes
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,268: INFO/PoolWorker-1] New Cassandra host <Host: 172.31.0.4 ap-southeast_1_cassandra> discovered
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,270: INFO/PoolWorker-1] New Cassandra host <Host: 172.31.10.93 ap-southeast_1_cassandra> discovered
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,270: INFO/PoolWorker-1] New Cassandra host <Host: 172.31.20.239 ap-southeast_1_cassandra> discovered
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,270: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Cassandra host 54.169.86.45 removed
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,271: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Cassandra host 54.169.132.4 removed
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,271: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Cassandra host 54.169.10.56 removed
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,659: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-06-28 14:39:32,672: INFO/MainProcess] celery@SanthavathisMBP ready.
[2017-06-28 14:39:37,578: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Failed to create connection pool for new host 172.31.0.4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dse/cluster.py", line 2217, in dse.cluster.Session.add_or_renew_pool.run_add_or_renew_pool (dse/cluster.c:41176)
    new_pool = HostConnection(host, distance, self)
  File "dse/hosts.py", line 329, in dse.hosts.HostConnection.__init__ (dse/hosts.c:5903)
    self._connection = session.cluster.connection_factory(host.address)
  File "dse/cluster.py", line 1025, in dse.cluster.Cluster.connection_factory (dse/cluster.c:14184)
    return self.connection_class.factory(address, self.connect_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
  File "dse/connection.py", line 382, in dse.connection.Connection.factory (dse/connection.c:8213)
    conn = cls(host, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/santha/Downloads/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dse/io/asyncorereactor.py", line 294, in __init__
    self._connect_socket()
  File "dse/connection.py", line 421, in dse.connection.Connection._connect_socket (dse/connection.c:9522)
    raise socket.error(sockerr.errno, "Tried connecting to %s. Last error: %s" % ([a[4] for a in addresses], sockerr.strerror or sockerr))
error: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('172.31.0.4', 9042)]. Last error: timed out
[2017-06-28 14:39:37,898: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Failed to create connection pool for new host 172.31.20.239:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dse/cluster.py", line 2217, in dse.cluster.Session.add_or_renew_pool.run_add_or_renew_pool (dse/cluster.c:41176)
    new_pool = HostConnection(host, distance, self)
  File "dse/hosts.py", line 329, in dse.hosts.HostConnection.__init__ (dse/hosts.c:5903)
    self._connection = session.cluster.connection_factory(host.address)
  File "dse/cluster.py", line 1025, in dse.cluster.Cluster.connection_factory (dse/cluster.c:14184)
    return self.connection_class.factory(address, self.connect_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
  File "dse/connection.py", line 382, in dse.connection.Connection.factory (dse/connection.c:8213)
    conn = cls(host, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/santha/Downloads/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dse/io/asyncorereactor.py", line 294, in __init__
    self._connect_socket()
  File "dse/connection.py", line 421, in dse.connection.Connection._connect_socket (dse/connection.c:9522)
    raise socket.error(sockerr.errno, "Tried connecting to %s. Last error: %s" % ([a[4] for a in addresses], sockerr.strerror or sockerr))
error: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('172.31.20.239', 9042)]. Last error: timed out
[2017-06-28 14:39:37,900: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Host 172.31.0.4 has been marked down
[2017-06-28 14:39:37,901: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Host 172.31.20.239 has been marked down
[2017-06-28 14:39:42,588: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Failed to create connection pool for new host 172.31.10.93:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dse/cluster.py", line 2217, in dse.cluster.Session.add_or_renew_pool.run_add_or_renew_pool (dse/cluster.c:41176)
    new_pool = HostConnection(host, distance, self)
  File "dse/hosts.py", line 329, in dse.hosts.HostConnection.__init__ (dse/hosts.c:5903)
    self._connection = session.cluster.connection_factory(host.address)
  File "dse/cluster.py", line 1025, in dse.cluster.Cluster.connection_factory (dse/cluster.c:14184)
    return self.connection_class.factory(address, self.connect_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
  File "dse/connection.py", line 382, in dse.connection.Connection.factory (dse/connection.c:8213)
    conn = cls(host, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/santha/Downloads/flask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dse/io/asyncorereactor.py", line 294, in __init__
    self._connect_socket()
  File "dse/connection.py", line 421, in dse.connection.Connection._connect_socket (dse/connection.c:9522)
    raise socket.error(sockerr.errno, "Tried connecting to %s. Last error: %s" % ([a[4] for a in addresses], sockerr.strerror or sockerr))
error: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('172.31.10.93', 9042)]. Last error: timed out
[2017-06-28 14:39:43,933: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Error attempting to reconnect to 172.31.0.4, scheduling retry in 2.0 seconds: [Errno None] Tried connecting to [('172.31.0.4', 9042)]. Last error: timed out
[2017-06-28 14:39:43,934: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Host 172.31.10.93 has been marked down
```

It is disregarding the address_translator=IdentityTranslator() setting which means **do no address translation** and **use the addresses provided in the cluster configuration**. Since my cassandra cluster is in AWS, and flask server runs outside of AWS, I need to use the public IP to connect to the cassandra nodes, but it is trying to connect to the Private IP.